# MAT over a calculated measure

Tags: ssas, olap

We have an OLAP SSAS cube with budget data on the fact table, and budget cathegory (sales, costs, salaries, ...) on a dimension. We have a bunch of formulas for our users but we are not able to create a MAT (moving annual total) on an already calculated measure.

```
create MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Sales budget]
as ([Dim budget].[Level_2].[Sales],[Measures].[Budget]);
-- Budget accounting only the values from the fact table with value "Sales" on the appropiate field of the cathegory

create MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Sales budget MAT]
as Aggregate(LastPeriods(12,[Dim time].[Months].CurrentMember), [Measures].
[Sales budget]);
-- A MAT over a calculated measure doesn't work, we obtain a #VALUE! error

create MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Budget MAT]
as Aggregate(LastPeriods(12,[Dim time].[Months].CurrentMember), [Measures].[Budget]);
-- A MAT over an original measure works as expected.
```

Any idea what are we doing wrong? How can we calculate this MAT?

Comment: Sorry for being off-topic. I cannot see why but sure I'm wrong. It's a specific question about OLAP SSAS cube MDX formula. Anyway I already found the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a blonde moment! Just using SUM instead of AGGREGATE and everything is ok as expected :(